# Fluentd with nginx syslog

Tags: docker, nginx, fluentd, syslog

I have ngnix and fluentd in Docker.
My ngnix config use syslog:

```
access_log syslog:server=server_ip:5140,tag=nginx_access json;
error_log syslog:server=server_ip:5140,tag=nginx_error info;
```

If i check traffic on 5140 i will see all of my log items that been sent by Nginx, but my fluentd doesn't react to this. I see no nginx log in fluentd container.

```
sudo tcpdump -i any -A dst port 5140

E.....@.@..x..............Z.<190>Jun  5 10:19:55 814eb5e65c49 nginx_access: { "time": "2023-06-05T10:19:55+00:00", "remote_addr": "xx.xxx.xx.xxx", "remote_user": "", "ssl_protocol_cipher": "TLSv1.2/ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256", "body_bytes_sent": "7635", "request_time": "0.087", "status": "200", "request": "GET / HTTP/1.1", "request_method": "GET", "http_referrer": "", "http_x_forwarded_for": "", "http_cf_ray": "", "host": "somesite.com", "server_name": "somesite.com", "upstream_address": "somesite2.com:3000", "upstream_status": "200", "upstream_response_time": "0.087", "upstream_response_length": "7635", "upstream_cache_status": "", "http_user_agent": "Uptime-Kuma/1.21.3" }
10:19:55.578431 veth541e95c Out IP kasie-frontend-common.41475 > 172.17.0.2.5140: UDP, length 659
E.....@.@..x..............Z.<190>Jun  5 10:19:55 814eb5e65c49 nginx_access: { "time": "2023-06-05T10:19:55+00:00", "remote_addr": "xx.xxx.xx.xxx", "remote_user": "", "ssl_protocol_cipher": "TLSv1.2/ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256", "body_bytes_sent": "7635", "request_time": "0.087", "status": "200", "request": "GET / HTTP/1.1", "request_method": "GET", "http_referrer": "", "http_x_forwarded_for": "", "http_cf_ray": "", "host": "somesite.com", "server_name": "somesite.com", "upstream_address": "somesite2.com:3000", "upstream_status": "200", "upstream_response_time": "0.087", "upstream_response_length": "7635", "upstream_cache_status": "", "http_user_agent": "Uptime-Kuma/1.21.3" }
```

My Fluentd conf is pretty simple:

```
<source>
    @type syslog
    port 5140
    tag syslog2
</source>

<match **>
    @type stdout
</match>
```

Fluentd docker logs:

```
docker logs fluentd -f
2023-06-05 10:19:11 +0000 [info]: init supervisor logger path=nil rotate_age=nil rotate_size=nil
2023-06-05 10:19:11 +0000 [info]: parsing config file is succeeded path="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf"
2023-06-05 10:19:11 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '1.16.1'
2023-06-05 10:19:11 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-mongo' version '1.6.0'
2023-06-05 10:19:11 +0000 [warn]: define <match fluent.**> to capture fluentd logs in top level is deprecated. Use <label @FLUENT_LOG> instead
2023-06-05 10:19:11 +0000 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>
  <source>
    @type syslog
    port 5140
    tag "syslog2"
  </source>
  <match **>
    @type stdout
  </match>
</ROOT>
2023-06-05 10:19:11 +0000 [info]: starting fluentd-1.16.1 pid=6 ruby="3.1.4"
2023-06-05 10:19:11 +0000 [info]: spawn command to main:  cmdline=["/usr/bin/ruby", "-Eascii-8bit:ascii-8bit", "/usr/bin/fluentd", "--config", "/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf", "--plugin", "/fluentd/plugins", "--under-supervisor"]
2023-06-05 10:23:07 +0000 [info]: init supervisor logger path=nil rotate_age=nil rotate_size=nil
2023-06-05 10:23:07 +0000 [info]: parsing config file is succeeded path="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf"
2023-06-05 10:23:07 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '1.16.1'
2023-06-05 10:23:07 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-mongo' version '1.6.0'
2023-06-05 10:23:07 +0000 [warn]: define <match fluent.**> to capture fluentd logs in top level is deprecated. Use <label @FLUENT_LOG> instead
2023-06-05 10:23:07 +0000 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>
  <source>
    @type syslog
    port 5140
    tag "syslog2"
  </source>
  <match **>
    @type stdout
  </match>
</ROOT>
2023-06-05 10:23:07 +0000 [info]: starting fluentd-1.16.1 pid=7 ruby="3.1.4"
2023-06-05 10:23:07 +0000 [info]: spawn command to main:  cmdline=["/usr/bin/ruby", "-Eascii-8bit:ascii-8bit", "/usr/bin/fluentd", "--config", "/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf", "--plugin", "/fluentd/plugins", "--under-supervisor"]
```

Why my fluentd container doesn't see upcoming logs?

Comment: Did you try receiving the raw messages using the [udp](https://docs.fluentd.org/input/udp) input plugin?

Comment: yes, same - doesn't work

Comment: `tcpdump` is from nginx or fluentd instance?

Comment: Both containers on same server

Comment: So, `tcpdump` is from the host? Are both containers pingable from each other? Or, did you verify with `telnet` or netcat `nc`? Please include the `docker run` commands for both.

Comment: fluentd: docker run -m 64m -d --restart=always -p 24224:24224 -p 24224:24224/udp -p 5140:5140/udp -v /home/user/fluentd_log:/fluentd/log --name internal-fluentd internal-fluentd:latest

Comment: nginx: docker run --restart always --name nginx -v /home/user/nginx-config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro -m 32m -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -d nginx

Comment: by some reason i can't check container visibility.
I just can't go inside of fluentd container by docker exec -it _container_id_ /bin/sh

Comment: So, there's a connectivity issue. Once that's fixed, it should work. You can try using the [host](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/host/) network for testing.